# when vim isnt run as just vim, getting no colors

Tags: vimrc, terminal

I recently started using `:set termguicolors` which enables 24 bit colors. However, this (along with the rest of my config) causes vim to display absolutely no colors whenever it is started in a different way:

- as `vimdiff`
- spawned by git for editing commit messages
- `EDITOR=vim crontab -e`

and so on...

I'd like to look for a change in environment variables and vim state but I'm not sure what are the right ways to dump those out so I can diff them.

Comment: Documentation mentions this in the `termguicolors` section. Try [`:help xterm-true-color`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#xterm-true-color).

Comment: @Tumbler41 `$TERM` is set the same, but `&t_8f` `&t_8b` are not present in the problem cases. I suspect if I explicitly add these values in .vimrc it should resolve the problem.

Comment: I also found that the provided example using colons does not work, it works for me when I use the semicolons.